# Creating relationship between two nodes using intermediate table

Tags: neo4j, cypher, neo4j-browser

I'm very new to the Neo4j world so please forgive me if this is a trivial question. I have 2 tables I've loaded into the database using LOAD CSV

artists:

```
artist_name,artist_id
"Bob","abc"
"Jack","def"
"James","ghi"
"Someone","jkl"
"John","mno"
```

agency_list:

```
"Agency"
"A"
"B"
"C"
"D"
```

Finally, I have an intermediary table that has the artist and the agencies that represent them.

artist_agencies:

```
artist_name,artist_id,agency
"Bob","abc", "A"
"Bob","abc", "B"
"Jack","def", "C"
"James","ghi", "C"
"Someone","jkl","B"
"Someone","jkl", "C"
"John","mno", "D"
```

Notice some artists can be a part of multiple agencies (which is why I didn't include the agency variable in the Artist table)

I'm trying to get four agency nodes that connect to each artist based on a :REPRESENTS relationship. Basically something like:
`(agency:Agency) - [:REPRESENTS] -> (artist:Artist)`

The code I've tried is:

```
LOAD CSV WITH HEADERS FROM "file:///agency_list.csv" as agencies
CREATE (agency:Agency {agency: agencies.Agency})

USING PERIODIC COMMIT 1000
LOAD CSV WITH HEADERS FROM "file:///artists.csv" as artists
CREATE (artist:Artist {artist: artists.artist_name, artist_id: artists.artist_id})

USING PERIODIC COMMIT 1000
LOAD CSV WITH HEADERS FROM "file:///artist_agencies.csv" as line 
CREATE (ag:Agency) - [:REPRESENTS] -> (ar:Artist {track_artist_uri:line.track_artist_uri})
```

So far I'm getting this, each blue node is a duplicate of an agency name. Rather than just having one single agency node that connects to all artists via the :REPRESENTS relationship. [result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AiKvN.png)

I guess my problem is that I don't know how to relate the artists table to the agency_list table via this intermediate artist_agencies table. Is there a better way to do this or am I on the right track?

Thanks!
Joey

Answer (score 0):

The `artist_agencies.csv` query needs to find the appropriate `Agency` and `Artist` nodes before creating a relationship between them. For example:

```
USING PERIODIC COMMIT 1000
LOAD CSV WITH HEADERS FROM "file:///artist_agencies.csv" as line
MATCH (ag:Agency) WHERE ag.agency = line.agency
MATCH (ar:Artist) WHERE ar.artist_id = line.artist_id
CREATE (ag)-[:REPRESENTS]->(ar)
```

*Aside: The `artist_agencies.csv` file does not need the `artist_name` column.*

[UPDATE]

If the `artist_agencies.csv` data could cause duplicate relationships to be created, replace `CREATE` with (the more expensive) `MERGE` to avoid that. And make sure you do not have duplicate `Agency` or `Artist` nodes.

Comment: Thanks! Definitely appreciate the answer and understand what you're suggesting here. I need to not only match up the artists to artists but the agencies to agencies as well. Problem is when I ran this I got 28mil relationships created which is _way_ over what it should be. Is there some sort of deduping I should be doing here?

Comment: See my updated answer. Also, make sure you do not have duplicate `Agency` or `Artist` nodes.

Comment: Also you'll want to make sure you have indexes on :Agency(agency) and :Artist(artist_id) for fast lookup of the nodes.

Comment: Noted. Updated using MERGE instead of CREATE and that did away with the duplicates. We're in business now, thank you cybersam for your help and InverseFalcon for the tip!